# Redux store not working, but there are no errors: React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use React-Redux within a React Native/Expo application. The data from the Redux store is not appearing in the UI, even though there are not any console error messages.

Here are some of the main files for the Redux store and the React app. Here I'm only showing the files for one slice. The others are pretty much identical.

**allRecipes.reducers.js**

```
const initialAllRecipes = [
  {
    name: "recipe one",
  },
  {
    name: "recipe two",
  },
];

export const allRecipesReducer = (allRecipes = initialAllRecipes, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "allRecipes/addRecipe":
      return [...allRecipes, action.payload];
    case "allRecipes/removeRecipe":
      return allRecipes.filter((r) => r.id !== action.payload.id);
    default:
      return allRecipes;
  }
};
```

**allRecipes.actions.js***

```
export const addRecipe = (newRecipe) => {
  return {
    type: "allRecipes/addRecipe",
    payload: newRecipe,
  };
};

export const removeRecipe = (target) => {
  return {
    type: "allRecipes/removeRecipe",
    payload: target,
  };
};
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { allRecipesReducer } from "./allRecipes/allRecipes.reducers";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  allRecipes: allRecipesReducer,
  // other reducers not shown here. . .
});
```

**index.js (in the `store` directory)**

```
// NOTE: in VS Code, createStore is striken through as deprecated.
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { rootReducer } from "./rootReducer";

export const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

**App.js (not showing all imports)**

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store/index.js";

// View Components
import AllRecipes from "./views/AllRecipes/AllRecipes";

export default function App() {
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Recipes" component={AllRecipes} />
          // other screens not shown here. . .
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

**AllRecipes.jsx**

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {store} from '../../store/index'

const AllRecipes = () => {
    const allRecipes = useSelector(state => state.allRecipes)
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>All Recipes</Text>
            {allRecipes.map(r => {
                <Text>{r.name}</Text>
            })}
        </View>
    )
}

export default AllRecipes;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `return` with `dispatch()` in action file like this in allRecipes.actions.js* file

```
dispatch({
    type: "allRecipes/removeRecipe",
    payload: target,
 });
```